# How to set a ng-click button on click (init)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I want to have a ng-click clicked if I reload the page every-time I do that the ng-click is disabled. How can I achieve that?

My code for clicking 
note: ther is a custom filter built in the click and it also has a ngclass after it zo its styled as well.

> a class="clear-completed" ng-click="taskfilter = 'todo'; infoTitel = 'To do'" ng-class="{'active' : taskfilter == 'todo'}" --- this line needs to be clicked on default.

```
<div style="display: block;" class="task-footer">
        <!-- <a id="clear-completed" ng-click="clear()" ng-show="hasDone()">
          Clear <span >{{(tasks.length - remaining())}} {{itemText()}}</span>.
      </a> -->
        <div class="mini-nav">
            <a class="clear-completed" ng-click="taskfilter = 'missed'; infoTitel = 'Deadline missed'" ng-class="{'active' : taskfilter == 'missed'}">
                <span>deadline missed</span>
            </a>
            <a class="clear-completed" ng-click="taskfilter = 'all'; infoTitel = 'All'" ng-class="{'active' : taskfilter == 'all'}">
                <span>show all </span>
            </a>
            <a class="clear-completed" ng-click="taskfilter = 'completed'; infoTitel = 'Completed'" ng-class="{'active' : taskfilter == 'completed'}">
                <span>show completed</span>
            </a>
            <a class="clear-completed" ng-click="taskfilter = 'todo'; infoTitel = 'To do'" ng-class="{'active' : taskfilter == 'todo'}" ng-init="">
                <span>to do</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="todo-count">{{remaining()}} of {{tasks.length}} remaining</div>
        <div class="todayDate"> Date today : {{ todayDate | date : "MMM d, y h:mm a"}}</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i already got it you can set the value of the wished ng-click into an ng-init on the same rule, that way it is selected on load.

```
<a class="clear-completed" ng-click="taskfilter = 'todo'; infoTitel = 'To do'" ng-class="{'active' : taskfilter == 'todo'}" ng-init="taskfilter = 'todo'; infoTitel = 'To do'">
```